# how can i use html index for Vue-router?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

For example I have index.html. I wanna to use it in `<router-link></router-link>`, but it not worked. I have one nav-bar, I want to use it for all of vue and html page, if you have an idea tell me please.

**I want to html document in my vue-router routes.**
please help.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to see how to put together a high quality question that will draw answers. You need to include code snippets and examples of how its not working so that it can be debugged.

Comment: You want to use the router in a Nagar linking to multiple pages? That doesn't sound like a single page application, for which the router is meant